# How can I bar outsiders from a town with the Towny mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-towny

Using the Towny plugin for Minecraft, how does one prevent people who are not the town's residents from being able to enter the town?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look over the documentation and I couldn't find away to do so. You could either request that as a feature [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/towny/issues/entry?template=Suggestion) or you could use WorldGuard to make regions around the towns, Then set flags so only the people you specify (or groups) are allowed into the area.

If you need more help with the second option - PM me on the Bukkit Forums (shadrxninga).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that plugin, but one method you could use is to build a wall and gate with building permissions for non-residents disabled near the entrance.  They way they wouldn't be able to open the gate, break the wall, or build stairs/ladders over it.

Comment: If you build the wall a few blocks in they won't even be able to build stairs over it and would be forced to use a gate or door which can be protected using the "use" permission for residents only. I don't think there is any other way with using *only* the towny plugin and not another area protection plugin.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by 'near the entrance'.  I don't see any other way either.